# Could Not Find Table 'Name'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm new to Ruby and can't solve this problem. I tried troubleshooting solutions in similar posts and none fixed the problem. Was hoping someone might have an idea on what's wrong. When I attempt to login, I'm told it cannot find the table `name'`. I'm able to create a user in the rails console and also able to locate it via `User.find_by(name: "")`. It also shows up in the database.

```
def create
  user = User.find_by(name: params[:session])
  if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
  else
     flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid username/password combination'
     render 'new'
  end
end
```

Migration:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not provided the key `:name`:

```
user = User.find_by(name: params[:session][:name])
```

Comment: WOW, can't believe it was something rather simple.  Fixed  THANK YOU!!  :)